# struct in a struct linked list

Tags: c++, function, struct, linked-list

I wanted to try a struct inside another struct in a linked list. But, I have a syntax error that says p (which is a pointer to the linked list) is uninitialized.

NOTE: I haven't learned this topic at university yet. So, it is expected to find errors in my code.

Here's the code I wrote.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct structType{
    int no;
    string name;
    float salary;
};
struct nodeType {
    structType s;
    nodeType *link;
};
void addFirst(nodeType **, nodeType*);
int main()
{
    nodeType *h=NULL, *p;
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter number #"<<i+1<<":";
        cin>>p->s.no;
        cout<<"Enter name #"<<i+1<<":";
        cin>>p->s.name;
        cout<<"Enter salary #"<<i+1<<":";
        cin>>p->s.salary;
        p->link=NULL;
        addFirst(&h,p);
    }
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
void addFirst(nodeType **h, nodeType *p){
    if(*h!=NULL)
    p->link=*h;
    *h=p;
}
```

Comment: You're doing `cin >> p->s.no`, but neither `p` (pointer to some node) nor the list is initialized at the moment. Should allocate some memory for it first...

Comment: @myaut How's that? I initialized at before the main(), so I allocated it in memory.

Comment: `p` is a local variable in `main`. How could you have initialized it before `main`?

Comment: nodeType *h = NULL, *p = new nodeType();

Comment: @melpomene I meant the linked list. Well.. I will try what you suggested.

Comment: @HariomSingh Thanks. I will try this now and tell you the result.

Comment: @HariomSingh It worked. Thank you very much.